# Installing CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04, for GTX1050

Tags: cuda, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I recently upgraded my laptop to an Acer Nitro5, with an Nvidia GeForce GTX1050 GPU. I need to install the CUDA toolkit on my laptop in order to run some machine learning simulations. I can update my Nvidia drivers to the latest ones, but cannit install CUDA on my laptop. On trying the hacks mentioned on several sources, I either end up with a black screen or a frozen Ubuntu lock screen. Could anyone provide a definitive guide on how to install CUDA for the GTX1050? It seems newer GPUs arent supported by CUDA 8.0.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but, have you tried the directions directly from Nvidia (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)?

Comment: @AndrewShum I did, ended up reinstalling my Ubuntu. I am doing it again atm.

Comment: After trying the "hacks" you found, did you try reinstalling the drivers? That fixed it for me when I had a similar problem.